# Disable the logs in keras

Tags: keras

Whenever I run a keras script, I always get the following log:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2017-06-22 21:54:17.148220: W
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-22 21:54:17.148242: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-22 21:54:17.148246: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-22 21:54:17.148249: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-22 21:54:17.148252: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-06-22 21:54:17.257119: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:901] successful 
NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be 
at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-06-22 21:54:17.257513: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 
with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 850M
major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.9015
pciBusID 0000:0a:00.0
Total memory: 3.95GiB
Free memory: 3.66GiB
2017-06-22 21:54:17.257528: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-06-22 21:54:17.257533: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-06-22 21:54:17.257539: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating 
TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 850M, 
pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0)
```

How do I disable these logs? I added `verbose = 0` in the methods but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Is there any way in which this can 
be solved?

Comment: This is coming from Tensorflow. Did you look at this  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8467

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following lines

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

Comment: @rjmessibarca The above lines worked for me. Can you please check it helps and accept the answer.

Comment: Can you please provide me with your tensorflow version?

Comment: I am using tensorflow-gpu version 1.6.0, and for additional info, I am using Keras 2.1.5

Comment: The above solution was tested on tensorflow cpu version of 1.4. Please look for gpu version solution.